# How would I take a user's input and reprint it in the Python shell

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

I'm fairly new to Python, and I'm working on a few things that would involve names. Something such as:

```
example = raw_input ("What is your name?: ")
```

How would I go about using this to have them answer it, and reprint their name such as:

```
print "Hello, {name}!"
```

Comment: Did you watch/read/listen to the tutorials for beginners?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
name = raw_input ("What is your name?: ")
print "Hello, " + name + "!"
```

Answer (score 3):

You were very close, you already had the correct template, now you have to tell it what the `{name}` should be replaced by:

```
>>> example = "Foo"
>>> "Hello, {name}!".format(name=example)
'Hello, Foo!'
```

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) for more information on using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Answer (score 0):

```
print "Hello, " + example + "!"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to acomplish your goal.

As was mentioned, you could use:

```
name = raw_input ("What is your name?: ")
print "Hello, " + name + "!"
```

or,

```
>>> example = "Foo"
>>> "Hello, {name}!".format(name=example)
'Hello, Foo!'
```

You could also use,

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?: ")
print "Hello, %s!" % name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print raw_input('Enter name :')
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.5 users, it can work like this:

```
name = input("What is your name? ")  
print "Hello, %s!" % (name)
```

That should work.